# How to compare rgb values, ignoring alpha

Tags: java, colors, bit-manipulation, rgb

As the question says, I would like to compare two colors using their rgb value, but I want to ignore alpha.
I don't get those bit shift and bit wise operators, so can you tell me is there a more elegant way to do this than the code below?

```
boolean compareRGB(Color c1, Color c2) {
    return c1.getRed() == c2.getRed() && c1.getGreen() == c2.getGreen() && c1.getBlue() == c2.getBlue();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you might want to look at using the `getColorComponents` method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getColorComponents(float[])) but passing in a null array, or a different array. It's sliiiightly cleaner maybe through array comparisons instead, but probably negligibly slower.

Comment: So I could do it like `c1.getColorComponents(null).equals(c2.getColorComponents(null))`?

Comment: There is `getRGB` so you can compare R G and B all at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted a bit-wise solution, it could look like this:

```
public static boolean equalsIgnoreAlpha(Color c1, Color c2) {
    return ((c1.getRGB() ^ c2.getRGB()) & 0x00_ff_ff_ff) == 0x00_00_00_00;
}
```

The first part

```
    c1.getRGB() ^ c2.getRGB()
```

is an exclusive or (or xor).  The result of which will be 0 for bits that match and 1 for bits that are different.  If the whole integer matched the result would just be zeroes for each bit.  Since we don't care about the alpha bits, the step

```
(...) & 0x00_ff_ff_ff
```

is an 'and' so the result has a 1 in for a bit only if there is a 1 on both sides.  Since 0x00_ff_ff_ff has no 1s for the alpha channel bits and 1 for all the RGB bits, this will only retain bits that are on for the RGB section.

Lastly, for a match we now expect that all the bits are off, so we can compare to 0.